# Debug KDevelop in KDevelop

Tags: c++, qt, kde-plasma, kdevelop, kdevelop4

I am trying to debug the KDevelop project by using my system KDevelop installation and I came across with a problem that my ( under debugging ) KDevelop application wont read the plugins from the local installation directory. Instead of that it try to use the system plugins by using this api:

```
KServiceTypeTrader::self() ->query
```

Is there any possibility to say to KDevelop to read the plugins information from a different resource lets say from one specified directory? I tried to change the code to do something like that:

```
    QDir dir("/home/alekstheod/workspaces/kdevelop/kdevelop/Installation/lib/kde4/plugins/");

QStringList files;
files = dir.entryList(QStringList("*"),
                      QDir::Files | QDir::NoSymLinks);


QStringList newFiles;
for( int i = 0; i < files.size(); i++ )
{
    newFiles.push_back(  dir.path() + "/" + files.at(i) );
}


//QStringList resources  = dirs.findAllResources("lib", "*.so", KStandardDirs::Recursive);
int a = newFiles.size();
std::cout << a << std::endl;
KPluginInfo::List res = KPluginInfo::fromFiles(newFiles);

return res;
```

but unfortunately it didn't help me. Probably I did something wrong. Please help :).

Answer (score 1):

Either remove the system one and use only the local one (eat your own dog food :D)

Or attach to the running process.